# How to pass BufferedImage data directly to OpenCL?

Tags: java, arrays, graphics, opencl

I'm attempting to use the JavaCL OpenCL binding library to utilize OpenCL kernels in my graphics rendering engine.

The problem I've run into is that I need to pass the array of BufferedImage pixel data directly into the OpenCL kernel so it can be modified.  Copying to a native Pointer object then  recopying back after computation will probably erase the performance benefit of using OpenCL in the first place, so I'm really trying to avoid that.

I was hopeful about maybe using an IntBuffer to directly modify pixel data, but the allocated buffer must be direct, which isn't possible if you use `wrap(int[])` (see the BridJ [documentation](http://nativelibs4java.sourceforge.net/bridj/api/stable/org/bridj/Pointer.html) for more info).

So now I'm stuck on how to make this work.  I'm asking for any proposed solutions or workaround to this, whether it involves using the array directly or just utliizing a different OpenCL feature with images, pointers, etc.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using java.nio.ByteBuffer. I believe that you could do something like this:

```
byte[] temp = new byte[54];
```

`ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(54);`

and then:`buffer.putInt(int someInt[]);`